# Settings on remotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

How can I apply a setting to a remote (or all remotes) when using `Remote SSH`? Specifically I want to unset `Terminal > Integrated: Inherit Env`, or equivalently in the JSON file:

```
"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false,
```

but this setting doesn't exist/apply in the remotes settings.